# How to generate Color code with UUID in Java

Tags: java, background-color, uuid

I want to create random color code with UUID in java, and i could not find best code for my problem.

Sample code for C# with GUID

```
public static Color ColorFromGuid(UUID id)
{
    var values = id.ToByteArray().Select(b => (int)b);
    int red = values.Take(5).Sum() % 255;
    int green = values.Skip(5).Take(5).Sum() % 255;
    int blue = values.Skip(10).Take(5).Sum() % 255;

    Color color = Color.FromArgb(200, red, green, blue);
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative :

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            getRandomColor(UUID.randomUUID());

        }

        /**
         * Method return a random color.
         */
        public static Color getRandomColor(UUID id) {

            byte[] bytes = UUID2Bytes(id);

            int r= Math.abs(bytes[0]);
            int g = Math.abs(bytes[1]);
            int b = Math.abs(bytes[2]);

            return  new Color(r, g, b);
        }

        public static byte[] UUID2Bytes(UUID uuid) {

            long hi = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
            long lo = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();
            return ByteBuffer.allocate(16).putLong(hi).putLong(lo).array();
        }
```

Comment: in android we import this class :
import android.graphics.Color; how  to resolve problem?

Comment: Android is not in the tags of the question. It should be added if u need a solution for Android. Also I think according to  SO rules this needs to  be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Android

```
 public  int getRandomColor(UUID id) {

        byte[] bytes = UUID2Bytes(id);

        int r= Math.abs(bytes[0]);
        int g = Math.abs(bytes[1]);
        int b = Math.abs(bytes[2]);
        int color = Color.argb(255, r, g, b);
        Log.e("Color",color+"");
        return  color;
    }

    public  byte[] UUID2Bytes(UUID uuid) {

        long hi = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
        long lo = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();
        Log.e("UUID2Bytes",hi+"  "+lo);
        return ByteBuffer.allocate(16).putLong(hi).putLong(lo).array();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public static Color colorFromGuid(UUID uuid) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[8]);
    bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
    int red = bb.get(0) & 0xff;
    int green = bb.get(1) & 0xff;
    int blue = bb.get(2) & 0xff;
    int alpha = bb.get(3) & 0xff;

    Color color = new Color(red, green, blue, alpha);
    return color;
}
```

You could also use the most significant bits from the UUID and generate 4 colours from each one, since this is only using a quarter half of the bits.

[Edited to only use 1 byte for each colour component.]

Comment: i got Error :
Color() in color cant to applied to

Comment: Well that code works fine and generates random colours.  What's the first line of the stack trace you're getting with the error?

Comment: i use this method in android.is it different for android?

Comment: in android we import this class :

Comment: import android.graphics.Color;

Comment: Yes, it's different.  Android doesn't actually use Java.  The language is basically Java, but the API is different.  You should tag your question with an Android tag and make it clear in the question's wording.